# Building LR(1) configuration lookahead

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I really have some troubles to cauculate the lookahead when building the LR(1) item sets, i had tried some lecture notes form different sites, but still...
My example is

```
S -> E + S | E
E -> num | ( S )
```

The item set is

```
I0:
S’ -> . S       $
S -> . E + S    $
S -> . E        $
E -> . num      +,$
E -> . ( S )    +,$

I1:
S ->E .+ S      $
S ->E .         $
```

The first item in set I0

```
S’ -> . S     $
```

is initialization.

The second item in set I0

```
S -> . E + S     $
```

means there is nothing on stack, we expect to read E+S, then reduce iff the token after E+S is  $.

The third item in set I0

```
S -> . E        $
```

means that we expect to read E and reduce iff the token after E is $.

Then i am confused about the fouth item in set I0,

```
E -> . num      +,$
```

I have no ideas why there are + and $ tokens.

and if anyone can explain this for me in plain English please.

**For each configuration [A –> u•Bv, a] in I, for each production B –> w in G', and for
each terminal b in First(va) such that [B –> •w, b] is not in I: add [B –> •w, b] to I.**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think i figured it out.
i am using the algorithm of

```
for set I0:
Begin with [S' -> .S, $]
Match [A -> α.Bβ, a]
Then add in [B -> .γ, b]
Where terminal b is FIRST(βa)

for set I1...In
Compute GOTO(I0,X)
Add in X productions and LOOKAHEAD token
```

In the example

```
S -> E + S 
S -> E
E -> num 
E -> ( S )
```

Firstly,

```
S’ -> . S       $
```

we try to match it to [A -> α.Bβ, a], That is 
A =S', α = ε, B = S , β = ε , a = $ and
FIRST(βa) = {$}
Add in [B -> .γ, b], which are

```
S -> . E + S    $                     ...1
S -> . E        $                     ...2
```

in I0.

Then, we need to add in productions for E as 1 and 2.
In this case, our [A -> α.Bβ, a] are 1 and 2.
Thus, FIRST(βa) = { + , $ }, and we have

```
E -> . num      +,$
E -> . ( S )    +,$
```

Now, we compute GOTO(I0, X)
For X = E
we move dot one position and found no productions need to be added. So we just add in second component $ from

```
S -> . E + S    $
S -> . E        $
```

which gives us I1

```
S ->E .+ S      $
S ->E .         $
```

and so on...

So, is this the correct and efficient way when building LR(1) item sets?

Answer (score 0):

For

```
E -> . num      +,$
E -> . ( S )    +,$
```

the +,$ indicate that only these tokens can follow a number or a closing parenthesis. Think about it: The grammar does noty allow adjacent num's or ()'s, they must either be at the end of the sentence or followed by a +.

As for translation request, it is a fancy way of saying how to calculate the set of tokens that can follow a given token. The +,$ above are an example. They are the only legal tokens that can follow num and ).

Comment: Thanks Rachard,
do you mean that for item
E ->.num    +,$
          and                        item       E ->.(S)    +,$
The lookahead tokens are actually FOLLOW(E).

if it is, then why the set of items in I1 is only the subset of FOLLOW(S)?

Thanks again.