# LR(1) - Items, Look Ahead

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, formal-languages, automata-theory

I am having difficulties understanding the principle of lookahead in LR(1) - items. How do I compute the lookahead sets?

Say for an example that I have the following grammar:

```
S -> AB
A -> aAb | b
B -> d
```

Then the first state will look like this:

```
S -> .AB , {look ahead}
A -> .aAb, {look ahead}
A -> .b,   {look ahead}
```

I know what look aheads are, but I don't know how to compute them. *I have googled for answers but couldn't find a webpage which explains this in a simple manner.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

I'll write down the first two states for your example:

```
S -> AB
A -> aAb | b
B -> d
```

#### State 0:

```
(1) S -> .AB, {$}   # Once we have done this rule it's EOF ($) 
(2) A -> .aAb, {d}  # from (1), after A there has to be a B whose first symbol has to be d
(3) A -> .b, {d}    # as above
```

#### State 1:

```
(4) A -> a.Ab, {d}   # from (2)
(5) A -> .aAb, {b}   # from (4), the symbol after the A has to be b
(6) A -> .b, {b}     # from (4), as above
(7) A -> b., {d}     # from (3)
(8) S -> A.B, {$}    # from (1) and (7)
(9) B -> .B, {$}     # from (8)
```

and so on, keep following the same shift/reduce/closure as you would for an LR(0) parser, but keep track of (**lookahead for**) the next symbol...
(State 2+ are longer, I don't recommend working them out by hand!)

I suggest looking into [Udacity's **Programming Languages**](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.udacity.com%2Fcourse%2Fcs262&ei=J66qUJ3uAoq20QWTmoGQBw&usg=AFQjCNFqXXDveASa9cxKH1pRQbQc4GvIEA) course to learn more about lexing and parsing. *There is also [an example on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser#Constructing_LR.281.29_parsing_tables) and a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989922/building-lr1-configuration-lookahead).*