# Look ahead in LR(1) parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

I have some problem to understand how to make look ahead in LR(1). I've already found this question about the same problem [LR(1) - Items, Look Ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459590/lr1-items-look-ahead) but this don't help me.

```
S'->.S,$
S->.L=R,$
S->.R,$
L->.*R,=/$
L->.id,=/$
R->.L,$
```

I understand the lookahead of S' and S production, but not the L and R one...
can you help me please? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a really nice treatment of LR/SLR/LALR parsing, I'd recommend [The Dragon Book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0321486811).

Constructing the LR(1) sets of items is in Section 4.7.2, the procedure `CLOSURE`.

For your example, consider performing "expanding" (during `CLOSURE`) the LR(1) item `S->.L=R,$`: the result are the LR(1) items

```
L->.*R,=
L->.id,=
```

The lookaheads are each terminal symbol in `FIRST("=R$")`, i.e. everything that follows the non-terminal in front of the dot, plus the lookahead, The new items' lookaheads are just `=` at this point.

Next, consider "expansion" of `S->.R,$`. Again, the lookaheads in the new items are all the terminal symbols in `FIRST("$"`): nothing follows the `R`, hence only the lookahead. This produces the item

```
R ->.L,$
```

Further expanding this item, using as lookaheads all the non-terminals in `FIRST("$")` gives us

```
L->.*R,$
L->.id,$
```

So, you can see that `L->.*R,=/$` in you original example is just a shorthand notation for the two individual items, `L->.*R,=` and `L->.*R,$`, each of them obtained along separate "expansion" chains.